# Application to verify code in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I had found this [page](https://www.javascript.com/try) and I would like to know how this editor is working, in example:

Some task to write `alert();` but If you write alert("lol"); then too is ok, and you can pass to next task,

How this editor is verifies the correctness? Any example? example can be realy simply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply runs your code with small **JS tests** to check if your code is correct.

**Example :**

Step 4 : Assign value "Gregg" to firstname. (`var firstname = "Gregg"`)

It simply has to check if `firstname` has been assigned a value.